# How to refresh foreground Activity with incoming SMS?

Tags: android, listview, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am developing SMS application. I have declared receiver in manifest as follows :

```
<receiver android:name="com.android.discrete.main.IncomingSMS" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

class for broadcastReceiver is as follows :

```
public class IncomingSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {

Context context;
DbManager DBmanager;
private long timestamp;
private String number;
static String body = "";
String msg="";
Cursor cursor;
String display_name;
String flag;
ChatActivity obj_chat;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


            if (bundle != null) {

                //—retrieve the SMS message received—
                Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

                for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
                    smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
                    timestamp = smsMessage[n].getTimestampMillis();
                    number = smsMessage[n].getOriginatingAddress();
                    body += smsMessage[n].getDisplayMessageBody();
                    display_name = Util.getContactName(context, number);
                    DBmanager = new DbManager(context);
                    cursor = DBmanager.Return_All_Contacts();
                    String [] contactArr = showcontactsInfo(cursor);
                Toast.makeText(context, contactArr[0]+"", 3000).show();
                    if(contactArr.length==0)
                    {}
                    else{
                    for(int i= 0;i<=contactArr.length;i++)
                    {

                        abortBroadcast();

                            }
                    blockMessage(context);

                    }
                        }
                    }

                }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }

            } // end for loop
        // bundle is null




    private String[] showcontactsInfo(Cursor cursor) {
        String[] contact = new String [cursor.getCount()];
        int i= 0;
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            contact[i] = cursor.getString(1);
            i++;
        }
        return contact;
    }
    private void blockMessage(Context context) {

        // instantiate DbMNager object to insert sms in database
        //formating receiving time:
        //SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss");

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d  HH:mm:ss a");
        String formatedTime = formatter.format(timestamp);
        flag = "0";
        DBmanager= new DbManager(context);
        DBmanager.open();
        DBmanager.Insert_sms_data(formatedTime ,display_name,body,flag);
        DBmanager.close();

        msg+= "SMS from " + number + " \n";
        msg += body + " \n";
        msg += formatedTime + " \n";
        msg += flag + " \n";
        Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ display_name + "; message: " + body);
        Toast.makeText(context,msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Toast.makeText(context, "New message received in Discrete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }    
}
```

This works fine as i can receive SMS and save it in SQLite database.
Now i have another activity having ListView in which i want to update as soon as new SMS is received and activity is in foreground. Code is as follows:

```
public class ChatActivity extends Activity {

Context context;
DbManager DBmanager;
private long timestamp;
private String number;
static String body = "";
//String msg="";
Cursor cursor;
String display_name;
//String flag;
static MyListAdapter adapter;
static ArrayList<String> item_id;
static ArrayList<String> item_phone_num;
static ArrayList<String> item_msg_body;
static ArrayList<String> item_time;
static ArrayList<String> item_flag;
static ArrayList<String> items;
private Button btn_send;
DbManager manager;
Cursor Cursor,cursor_new;
//ViewHolder holder12;
String contact_for_chat;
String contact_no;
String message_body = "";
Calendar c;
SimpleDateFormat sdf;
String time;
EditText et_chat;
String flag;
String msg = "";
ListView lv_chat;
int position;
String[] from = new String[]{"Message_body","Time"};
int[] toIDs = new int[]{R.id.msg_body,R.id.time};
BroadcastReceiver IncomingSMS =  new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateList();
}};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        contact_for_chat = bundle.getString("contact_name");
        contact_for_chat = contact_for_chat.replace(" ", "");
        contact_no = Util.getContactNumber(contact_for_chat, ChatActivity.this);


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contact_no, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        manager = new DbManager(this);
        Cursor = manager.Return_SMS(contact_for_chat);

        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
        time = sdf.format(c.getTime());


        item_id = new ArrayList<String>(Cursor.getCount());
        item_phone_num = new ArrayList<String>(Cursor.getCount());
        item_msg_body = new ArrayList<String>(Cursor.getCount());
        item_time = new ArrayList<String>(Cursor.getCount());
        item_flag = new ArrayList<String>(Cursor.getCount());
        findViews();
        showList();
        //setActionBar();

        btn_send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SendSMS();
                showList();
                //updateList() ;

            }
        });

        lv_chat.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                int itemId = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(position));
                Cursor.moveToPosition(itemId);
                int messageId = Cursor.getInt(0);
                deleteMessage(messageId);
            }});
    }

    private void showList() {

        showEvents(Cursor);
        adapter = new MyListAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_chat, Cursor, from, 
                toIDs);

        lv_chat.setAdapter(adapter);
        //updateList() ;


    }

    private void findViews() {
        et_chat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_chat);
        btn_send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        lv_chat = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv_chat.setDivider(this.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));

    }

    protected void SendSMS() {

        SmsManager sms_manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        message_body = et_chat.getText().toString();
        ArrayList<String> parts = sms_manager.divideMessage(message_body);
        sms_manager.sendMultipartTextMessage(contact_no, null, parts, null, null);
        flag = "1";
        manager.Insert_sms_data(time, contact_for_chat, message_body,flag);

        if(message_body.length()>0)
        {
            et_chat.setText("");
        }
        updateList() ;
}
private void showEvents(Cursor cursor) {

        int i=0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            item_id.add(i+"");
            item_time.add(cursor.getString(1));
            item_msg_body.add(cursor.getString(3));
            item_phone_num.add(cursor.getString(2));
            item_flag.add(cursor.getString(4));
            i++;
        }

    }
    public class MyListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

        Cursor myCursor;
        Context myContext;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context, int layout,
                Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
            myCursor = c;
            myContext = context;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return item_msg_body.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return item_msg_body.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return item_msg_body.get(position).hashCode();
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

            View v = arg1;
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (v == null) {

                LayoutInflater layoutinf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = layoutinf.inflate(R.layout.row_chat, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                //  holder.tv_contact = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.phone_num);
                holder.tv_sms_body = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_body);
                holder.tv_time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);

                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }

            if(item_flag.get(position).equals("1"))
            {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams dateparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                dateparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                dateparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.msg_body);

                holder.tv_sms_body.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_green);
                holder.tv_sms_body.setLayoutParams(params);
                holder.tv_time.setLayoutParams(dateparams);
            }
            else if(item_flag.get(position).equals("0"))
            {
                holder.tv_sms_body.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_yellow);

            }

            //holder.tv_contact.setText("" + item_phone_num.get(position));
            holder.tv_sms_body.setText(item_msg_body.get(position));
            holder.tv_time.setText(item_time.get(position));

            return v;
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder {

        private TextView tv_contact;
        private TextView tv_sms_body;
        private TextView tv_time;

    }

    public void updateList() 
    {
        item_id.clear();
        item_time.clear();
        item_msg_body.clear();
        item_phone_num.clear();
        item_flag.clear();
        Cursor = manager.Return_SMS(contact_for_chat);
        showEvents(Cursor);
        adapter = new MyListAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_chat, Cursor, from, 
                toIDs);
        lv_chat.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(IncomingSMS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        //registerReceiver(IncomingSMS, null);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        registerReceiver(IncomingSMS, filter);
        updateList();
        super.onResume();
    }
```

Problem is that when i receive SMS then ListView is updated automatically but result is not as expected.When SMS is received then it combines previous SMS with new one i.e see in this image fisrt SMS was "Hi" second SMS was "How are you" but its combines both SMS as "Hi How are you". What is the reason ? How it can be fixed ????
Any help will be appreciated .
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use  [Cursor Loader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) here are some tutorial :- 
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

so your app design would be like this :-

(new sms) ----> (broadcast reciever inserts into db) -----> (cursor loader will refresh your foreground activity)

Comment: i don't want Activity to be fired when new SMS is received. I just want to fix that issue i have depicted through image :)

Comment: no dude , ur activity will not get fired , first two process will run in background , when ur BR will insert new row in db , your cursor loader will get a notification and then your cursor loader will update the ui , i never said anything about activity , if your app is not running then nothing will happen besides db insertion !! and when its running cursor loader will load the cursor from db and update your UI , its pretty easy and straight forward to use , if you are unaware of cursor loader please go through the link that i have provided !!